# Calling web services from Jasmine Test

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am attempting to write some black box tests to some web services. In an attempt to do this, I'm using Jasmine. I would like to know how to call a web service from Jasmine. I currently have the following setup:

```
describe('Web Service', function () {
  describe('-> endpoint', function() {
    describe('-> create', function() {
      var response = null;
      beforeEach(function(done) {
        // execute a call to the web service here
        if (done) {
          done();
        }
      });

      it('should run correctly', function(done) {
        if (done) {
          done();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

How do I call a web service from Jasmine?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock) to mock a response and assert that your code has called the service and received the correct response and then did its job correctly, or, if you really want nock can even allow your code to perform the actual call to the web service.

Otherwise if you just want to call the webservice from within your test you most likely have an API client somewhere where you can just perform the call yourself.

```
describe('My Test', function (done) {
    beforeEach(function () {
        var myApiClient = new MyApiClient();
        //unless you're using promises
        this.response = myApiClient.synchronousGet('http://someURL.com');
    });
});
```

Jasmine itself isn't, and shouldn't be, responsible for calling your web services, that should come from within your unit under test.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't send ajax requests from your tests because you'll be dependant of the services to run your tests... And a bad response from your webservices doesn't absolutely mean that your code is not running correctly.

A good way to do it is to mock the ajax request (as limelights said), but Jasmine has an ajax module ready to help you with this. See http://jasmine.github.io/edge/ajax.html

This Jasmine plugin will allow you to catch the calls to a service and replace it with your fresh configured response that will be always the same (because you should know the exact response to test correctly your service.

Anyway, if you absolutely want to call your service, I think you'll have to code it in JS in your tests (not recommanded to write such code in your tests. Better write function that will be tested too). As I know, Jasmine doesn't provide you this kind of helper, it's just for tests purposes.